# WordPress database error - quick review

Tags: widgets, sql

This error appears when I try to activate one option in widget. I broke it in multiple lines so it may be easier to review. I hope it should be very quick to fix code for someone who is familiar with SQL. I appreciate your time!

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'post_status='publish' AND post_type in ('post') GROUP BY ID OR' at line 14]

```
SELECT ID as post_id,
SUM(x.facebook_shares+x.twitter_shares) as a, 
SUM(x.facebook_shares - x.facebook_shares_start +x.twitter_shares - x.twitter_shares_start) as d 
,post_title, 
post_content FROM wp_top_stories x inner join wp_posts on ID=id_post 
AND dt_day>'2017-09-19' WHERE ( (x.facebook_shares - x.facebook_shares_start +x.twitter_shares - x.twitter_shares_start) >0 ) 
post_status='publish' AND post_type in ('post') GROUP BY ID ORDER BY d DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: is one of your plugins creating this SQL request ?

Comment: No, it is commercial plugin but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an AND before post_status='publish'